# How to open image in default image viewer of Android

Tags: java, android, image

I use following code to open default file manager and find images but when I click on image the Activity closes.

I can select file on the top of the Activity I see the word `Open` but when I tap on it it just closes itself.

**I would like to catch this event and open selected image in full screen mode in my custom Activity.**

```
int PICKFILE_REQUEST_CODE=10;
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("*/*");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
startActivityForResult(intent, PICKFILE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Comment: *`just closes itself.`* it means your app getting crash Please share that crash log with question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got this working.

**1. Start File Manager to select file (In my case it is  image file)**

```
int PICKFILE_REQUEST_CODE=33; // class property

Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT); // It helps to get Image Uri 
intent.setType("image/*"); // Filter only images to open
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
startActivityForResult(intent, PICKFILE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

**2. Use   onActivityResult event to get result of selection of the intent with PICKFILE_REQUEST_CODE**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

if (requestCode == PICKFILE_REQUEST_CODE ) {
   if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
      Uri imageUri = data.getData();     
      Intent intent = new Intent(this, ImageViewer.class);
      intent.putExtra("imageUri", imageUri.toString());
      startActivity(intent); // Start new intent to see the full sized image ImageViewer
    }
}
```

**3. And withing ImageViewer we can do all staff with Image**

```
public class ImageViewer extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageView imgView;
    private String fullScreenInd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_viewer);

        Uri myUri = Uri.parse(getIntent().getExtras().getString("imageUri"));
        imgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.fullImageView);
        imgView.setImageURI(myUri);

        imgView.getLayoutParams().height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        imgView.getLayoutParams().width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        imgView.setAdjustViewBounds(false);
        imgView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this code

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
 intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
 intent.setDataAndType(fileuri, "image/*");
 startActivity(intent);
```

**Edit:**

First use the method to Open gallery for choosing a image file

```
private void dispatchImageGalleryIntent() {

    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

    try {
        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, REQUEST_CODE_IMAGE_GALLERY);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Then in `onActivityResult`

```
 if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_IMAGE_GALLERY){
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
         Uri fileuri = intent.getData();
    }
 }
```

Use `fileUri` to open Image.

Comment: Hi! How do I know the `file` if I use default File Manager? It shows 1000 files and I select the one only and see the menu on the top OPEN. So I guees should be the event where I can get the argument with data of selected file. How to do it? Please explain. Thank you!

Comment: You have to get the file path or `Uri` to open it.

Comment: Check this it might help http://codetheory.in/android-pick-select-image-from-gallery-with-intents/

Comment: Thanks for the link but it my case app craches when I tap on OPEN menu after selecting the file and `onActivityResult` does not fire at all.

Comment: `Process: android.apps.ktk.company.razrez, PID: 18445
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=33, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/9C33-6BBD:DCIM/Camera/20180512_084917.jpg flg=0x1 launchParam=MultiScreenLaunchParams { mDisplayId=0 mBaseDisplayId=0 mFlags=0 } }} to activity {android.apps  .... .MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.getAuthority()' on a null object reference `